# JQuery Slider Responsive Design Trouble

Tags: jquery, slider, responsive

I am having trouble trying to make my JQuery slider responsive (If I resize the window half of the image gets cropped off), The thing is, using viewport and media queries everything else on my website is responsive, just the slider is not.

Here is my JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Syystole/4r4qnojo/3/

HTML

```
<style>
img {max-width: 100%}
.side-by-side{
display: flex;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="WrapperPage">

<section id="slider">
  <ul class="mySlide">
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="Slider Image"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="Slider Image"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="Slider Image" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="Slider Image" /></li>
  </ul>
<span class="button back">Back</span>
<span class="button next">Next</span>
</section>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var sliderList;
$(function() {

  var sliderWrapper = $("#slider");
  sliderList = sliderWrapper.children("ul");
  var sliderItems = sliderList.children("li");
  var count = 1;
  var sliderItems = $('ul.mySlide > li').length;
  var sliderDuration = 1000;
  var countLimitReached = "";


  function animateSlider(direction, duration, countLimitReached) {
      if (direction === "+") {
        count--;
      if(countLimitReached == "start"){
        sliderList.animate({
          "margin-left": "-=2400px"
        }, duration);
        count = 4;
        return;
        } else
      {       
        sliderList.animate({
          "margin-left": "+=800px"
        }, duration);
        }
      } 

      else if (direction === "-") {
        count++;

       if(countLimitReached == "end"){
        sliderList.animate({
          "margin-left": "+=2400px"
        }, duration);
        count = 1;
        return;
        } else
      {
          sliderList.animate({
            "margin-left": "-=800px"
          }, duration);
        }
      }
  }

    function checkCount(count, sliderItems){
    if(count === sliderItems){
      return "end";
    }
    else if(count == 1){
    return "start";
    }
    return "";
  }

  $(".button").on('click', function() {
        countLimitReached = checkCount(count, sliderItems);
        if ($(this).hasClass("back")) {
        animateSlider("+", sliderDuration, countLimitReached);
      } else {
        animateSlider("-", sliderDuration, countLimitReached);
      }
    countLimitReached = "";
  });
});
```

CSS

```
#slider {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 82%;
overflow:hidden;
}

#slider ul {
list-style: none;
width: 3500px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#slider li{
float: left;
width: 800px;
}

img{
width:100%;
}

.button {

font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
display: block;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.back {
float: left;
}

.next {
float: right;
}
```

Comment: i thinks you can use your code instead this https://jsfiddle.net/tLhs1v59/

Comment: I'm trying to figure it out with my code though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have some changed for your slider, i hope useful for you this time.

```js
$(function() {

  var ul = $("#slider ul");
  var slide_count = ul.children().length;
  var sliderDuration = 1000;
  var slide_width_pc = 100.0 / slide_count;
  var slide_index = 0;
  
  ul.find("li").each(function(indx) {
    var left_percent = (slide_width_pc * indx) + "%";
    $(this).css({"left":left_percent});
    $(this).css({width:(100 / slide_count) + "%"});
  });

  // Listen for click of prev button
  $("#slider .prev").click(function() {
    if(slide_index ==0){
     slide_index = slide_count;
    }
    slide(slide_index - 1);
  });

  // Listen for click of next button
  $("#slider .next").click(function() {
     if((slide_count-1) == slide_index){
     slide_index = -1;
    }
    slide(slide_index + 1);
  });

  function slide(new_slide_index) {

    if(new_slide_index < 0 || new_slide_index >= slide_count) return; 

    var margin_left_pc = (new_slide_index * (-100)) + "%";

    ul.animate({"margin-left": margin_left_pc}, sliderDuration, function() {

      slide_index = new_slide_index

    });

  }

});
```

```css
#slider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

#slider ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#slider li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 33.333333%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: none;
}

#slider li img {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#slider button {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align:center;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

#slider button.prev {
  left: 0;
}

#slider button.next {
  right: 0;
}

#slider button:hover, .slider button:active {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

#slider .content {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding: 0 1em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#slider .content a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <div class="WrapperPage">

     <div id="slider">
  <ul class="mySlide">
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="Slider Image"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="Slider Image"/>
    
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="Slider Image"/>
    </li>
    
  </ul>
  <button class="prev">prev</button>
  <button class="next">next</button>
</div>

    </div>

  </body>
```